# Backend to backend communication through REST with Keycloak protected backends

Tags: keycloak

I have two webapps. Each has frontend(AngularJS) and backend(Java). Each frontend has it's own public access type configuration keycloak.json file. Each backend has it's own bearer-only access type configuration keycloak.json file. Each frontend app is working fine with it's own backend. My task is make REST call to each other(backend to backend). How could I achieve that? Because on each backend REST sevices are protected by checking token validity.

Comment: Good question! I guess a more appropriate place to ask this kind of question is the official [Keycloak user mailing list](https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/keycloak-user).

Comment: @Eazy Did you solve it? i'm facing exactly the same right now

Answer (score 1):

If all those backend services are secured by keycloak, look at KeycloakRestTemplate extension of RestTemplate in Spring keycloak adapter. KeycloakRestTemplate is imported as part of keycloak-spring-security-adapter jar dependency.

Basically, it uses KeycloakClientRequestFactory and internally, adds Authorization header (for currently authenticated principal) to all requests for service to service calls.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/client/KeycloakRestTemplate.java

Comment: But if I'm not using Spring? What to do than?

Comment: @Eldar, of course, you don't have to use spring. You can take the access token from the original request from UI to backend and simply inject it into the header of outgoing request to another backend service. If not spring RestTemplate, how are you making that service to service call?

Comment: I tried this with no luck. Second backend throws exception "Token issuer is different". Two project have different subdomain names: backend1.project.com and backend2.project.com

Comment: Does both of projects use same keycloak? Token issuer is a keycloak realm which process authentication flow. Application can use external requests to other backends only within same realm (Except you are configured multi-tenancy)